# Unity3D Player movement: Looking up makes my player jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I move forward while looking up my player jumps or at least attempts to fly. If I press Space bar and do move forward while looking up my player jumps even higher. I honestly have no idea on whats's going on. My prediction is the forward. If I look up Forward is relative to where I'm looking.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class P_MOVEMENT : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float ACCELERATION = 10.0f;
    private float GRAVITY = -5.0f;
    private float SPEED = 5.0f;

    private float RUNNING_SPEED = 2.0f;
    private float JUMP_IMPULSE = 2.5f;

    private bool isRunning = false;

    CharacterController P_CC;
    Vector3 P_MOVE;

    //Camera Moving Mouse
    private float X_AXIS = 0.0f;
    private float Y_AXIS = 0.0f;
    private float CAMERA_SPEED = 2.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        P_CC = GetComponent<CharacterController>();    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(P_CC.isGrounded)
        {
            // Player Movement
            P_MOVE = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

            // Special Cases Check

            // Running 
            isRunning = ( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ) ? true : false;
            P_MOVE = (isRunning) ? P_MOVE * SPEED * RUNNING_SPEED : P_MOVE * SPEED;

            // Jumping
            if(Input.GetAxis("Jump") > 0)
            {
                P_MOVE += Vector3.up * JUMP_IMPULSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            P_MOVE += Vector3.up * GRAVITY * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Player Camera Movement
        X_AXIS += CAMERA_SPEED * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        Y_AXIS -= CAMERA_SPEED * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        // Restrict 90 Degree Up and Down
        Y_AXIS = Mathf.Clamp(Y_AXIS, -60f, 90f);

        // Update Rotation
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(Y_AXIS, X_AXIS, 0.0f);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        P_CC.Move(P_MOVE * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably right. Your transform.forward is about the local GameObject coordinates instead of the global ones.

You could try to update only transform.forward.x and transform.forward.z. So you will ignore transform.forward.y. This way the player should not move up.

Something like this:

```
P_MOVE = transfrom.forward.x * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + transform.forward.z * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
```

Comment: Thank you, your comment actually made me fix it. There was a little problem with your code tho.
Since you are using `transform.forward.x`  and `transoform.forward.z` they become floats and apparently you can't add floats and Vector3

I'm 100% sure there is a better way of doing this but What I did was
`P_MOVE = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
P_MOVE.y = 0.0f;`